# Not able to write BLOB to Memory mapped file using nio

Tags: java, jdbc, blob, memory-mapped-files

I want to write a memoery mapped file from a BLOB field. The field can have uncompressed, gzip or bzip2 compressed data. Right now I have used the follwing code to read the blob and write into the file using FileOutputStream, but I want to make it more faster.

```
private static void writeBLOB(
Statement myStatement,
String fileName
  ) throws SQLException, IOException {

// step 1: initialize the LOB column to set the LOB locator
myStatement.executeUpdate(
  "INSERT INTO EDR_RRP_INFO(file_name, DEC_EDR_INFO) " +
  "VALUES ('" + fileName + "', EMPTY_BLOB())"
);

// step 2: retrieve the row containing the LOB locator
ResultSet blobResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery(
  "SELECT DEC_EDR_INFO " +
  "FROM EDR_RRP_INFO " +
  "WHERE file_name = '" + fileName + "' " +
  "FOR UPDATE"
);
blobResultSet.next();

// step 3: create a LOB object and read the LOB locator
BLOB myBlob =
  ((OracleResultSet) blobResultSet).getBLOB("DEC_EDR_INFO");

// step 4: get the buffer size of the LOB from the LOB object
int bufferSize = myBlob.getBufferSize();

// step 5: create a buffer to hold a block of data from the file
byte [] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];

// step 6: create a file object
File myFile = new File(fileName);

// step 7: create a file input stream object to read
// the file contents
FileInputStream myFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(myFile);

// step 8: create an input stream object and call the appropriate
// LOB object output stream function
OutputStream myOutputStream = 3myBlob.getBinaryOutputStream();

// step 9: while the end of the file has not been reached,
// read a block from the file into the buffer, and write the
// buffer contents to the LOB object via the output stream
int bytesRead;

while ((bytesRead = myFileInputStream.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) {

  // write the buffer contents to the output stream
  // using the write() method
  myOutputStream.write(byteBuffer);

} // end of while

// step 10: close the stream objects
myFileInputStream.close();
myOutputStream.close();

System.out.println("Wrote content from file " +
  fileName + " to BLOB");

 } // end of writeBLOB()
```

Can anyone help me on that? I have tried with different methods but failed.

Comment: What do you mean with _failed_ in "I have tried with different methods but failed."?

Answer (score 0):

The best speedup you will get if you don't create the file at all :-)

Other than that, for good performance, `bufferSize` should be 8 * 1024 or larger. You could use NIO, but typically it will not help a whole lot in my experience.

There is a bug however: your program doesn't take into account that the `read` method doesn't fully read all bytes. You need to use `myOutputStream.write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);` instead of `myOutputStream.write(byteBuffer);`

Comment: Actually the content of the BLOB is cached into the local cache file and multiple instances of my application will access the same memory mapped file. So what is best approach to get the best performance?

Comment: "...tried with different..." what I mean to say that, I have tried to write direcltly BLOB content to memory mapped file by opening a file channel of a RAF.

Comment: In Java, typically a file is mapped in memory using `FileChannel.map`. This could be done using `RandomAccessFile.getChannel().map(...)`. So maybe this is the information you are looking for, how to map a file in memory?

Comment: Thanks. Actually after writing the file from BLOB, I have also opened the channel using Random Access File as you have mentioned. But now while writing the file from BLOB, I have used OutputStream instead I want to write the file from BLOB using any faster method preferably java nio. Then I will open the file as memory mapped file as you mentioned. So I want any faster method for writing BLOB to file, where BLOB may contains zipped data also, and in that case I need to uncompress and write the file at the same time.

Comment: What about changing the title to "Fastest way to create a memory mapped file?"